# Saving data in a custom EAV attribute

Tags: magento, attributes, save, entity-attribute-value

I've created a custom EAV attribute that is added onto my customer table and I'm trying to create a function that will populate it.

What I currently have is:

```
    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->load(22);
    $customer->setProfession("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    $customer->save();
```

But for some reason it's not saving to it. I can set standard fields like Firstname but I'm having difficulty saving any of the custom EAV attributes I create.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2):

First,
test it with setData() function to validate that you are using the right attribute name.

```
$customer->setData('profession', 'some profession');er code here
```

Second,
How did you create that attribute ?
I recommend doing it this way (in install/upgrade file .php):

```
$installer = $this; 
$installer->startSetup();
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$entityTypeId = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

//drop attribute if it already exists (to avoid problems) 
$setup->removeAttribute('customer', 'profession'); 
//now recreate the attribute
$this->addAttribute('customer', 'profession', array(
'type' => 'varchar',
'input' => 'text',
'label' => Mage::helper('core')->__("Customer profession"),
'global' => 1,
'visible' => 1,
'required' => 0,
'user_defined' => 1,
'visible_on_front' => 1));
//adding the attribute in backend Forms in case you want that
Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer', 'profession')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer', 'customer_edit'))
    ->save();
```

Let me know if it working now for you .